# Rule in Geneos to trigger based on last modified TS

Tags: geneos

I am creating a rule in Geneos.I got the last modified Timestamp value from the database table which i put in path alias as "last_modified_ts".How should i write a block in the Geneos rule so that it will trigger if last_modified_ts is less than 1.5 hours from now?